# How to use the index specified in Filebeat in logstash.yml?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using `Filebeat` to send log files over to my `Logstash` with the following configurations:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - ${PWD}/filebeat-volume/data/*.txt

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["elk:5044"]
  index: "custom-index"

setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"
```

and

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "<WHAT SHOULD GO HERE???>"
  }
}
```

In `filebeat.yml`, I am specifying an index ("custom index"). How can I set the same index in my `logstash.yml` to be sent to `Elasticsearch`?

Comment: I would add the same index name "cusotm-index" notice the typo in your filebeat configuration.
Actually, I would remove the index from the filebeat and set it only on the logstash. (That is how I have it setup, I don't set any indexon the filebeat, only on the logstash)

Comment: Thanks for your response! The thing is I have one elk container up whose Logstash is listening on port 5044 for new logs from many other Filebeat containers (all on the same docker network but created at random times). Now, since new logs come from many places, which will want a different index for their logs, it is Filebeat which should determine the index name. (Thanks for pointing out the typo BTW!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want now, you should set Logstash with below output configuration, this way it will pass the index set in filebeat to Elasticsearch.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
  }
}
```

[Point 2 in this example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html#_accessing_metadata_fields)